# 404 Error When Trying To Unregister Push Notifications Quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox

When a user in my app wants to unregister push notifications I use the follow code...

```
[QBRequest unregisterSubscriptionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
  //stop receiving notifications
} errorBlock:^(QBError *error) {
  //error
}];
```

I always get the following error.

```
@"NSErrorFailingURLKey" : @"https://api.quickblox.com/subscriptions.json"   
@"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Expected status code in (200-299), got 404"
```

There is a valid quickblox session and the user is logged in.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the subscriptions for the particular user in QuickBlox Admin Panel?

If there are no subscriptions for user, QuickBlox will return 400+ error.

Also please look at *response.error.reasons* and *response.error.error.localizedRecoverySuggestion* to find more details.

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to get the chat side working then will attempt this. Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28752710/2105498 and see if you can help!